# How to delete a record in django within the views?

Tags: django, crud

I'm trying to set up my first CRUD page using django and so far I've got to the D part, respectivly - delete. Following the information found on the internet, I tried this: `SomeModel.objects.filter(id=id).delete()`, but that threw out an error: `id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)` so could you tell me what am I doing wrong in order to make it work please?

Thank you.

Comment: That code wouldn't give that error. You should show the whole view you are actually using, since you are obviously calling the built-in `id()` function somewhere.

Comment: can you provide some more code

Comment: Also instead of following information "off the internet", you should do the tutorial, it will show you `EXACTLY` how to do this.

Comment: I am following a tutorial right now, but I wanna try a different approach. The tutorial is telling me how to do it if I were to click delete -> get directed to a template, where I have to accept that delete and then the magic happens. I want to click on the delete button and it disappears, but so far without any success.

Comment: Sounds like your view (or wherever this code is living) doesn't have a variable `id`, so check what's being passed through / set up there (which is basically just another way of saying what @DanielRoseman said a while back :-).

Comment: I don't understand why you have replied to various comments here, but not posted the actual code as requested, if you really want someone to help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(id=id)[0].delete()
```

Comment: Because, why recommend a `filter()` solution and then evaluate it using list notation and THEN `.delete()` when `m = SomeModel.objects.get(id=id) m.delete()` is the better way.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing when I recieved that error.

Comment: Actually, the downvote was because OP's syntax was perfectly valid, and this answer does not add anything.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I just wanted to point that, if I am not wrong, the result of a filter is a list, not a single element.

Comment: Well, the result is a QuerySet, which itself has a `delete()` method.